# Bootstrap window closes after alert statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've below bootstrap modal. I'm just showing only 2 fields here. But I've more than 10 fields which are all mandatory. I'm doing `javascript` validation on click of Add button in `Add_click();` and alerting user that `All fields are mandatory`. After click on Alert, the Modal window just goes off. I need this window to be retained until user gives all the details.

```
<div id="modalUserAddition" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 600px">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            &times;<span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">User Details</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="txtUserName" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="User Name"   />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="Close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        <button type="button" id="Add" onclick="Add_click();" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Add User</button>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried below code, but it didn't work for me.

```
alert('All fields are mandatory!');
    //$('#modalUserAddition').modal('toggle');
    $('#modalUserAddition').modal({
        show: true
    });
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from the Add button and close the modal in Add_click where the data is proven valid by adding:

```
$('#modalUserAddition').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are clicking outside the modal when you click on the alert, and it is closing the modal due to its native behavior. You can use the backdrop option. Passing this option with value `static` will prevent closing the modal after clicking outside the modal.

```
 <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static">
    Launch demo modal
 </button>
```

Or you can do it via JavaScript

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static'})
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/ExviJolAjT)**

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. On click of alert message, modal was closing. jazZRo's suggestion worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap, perhaps a better alternative would be to use its [native alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts).

It would avoid your current issue and be more consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll definitely give a try on bootstrap alert window.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me putting `data-backdrop="static"` in the button and  `return false;` when returned the validations results.